# 'Enough' : adverb of degree modifying verbs

Tags: verbs, adverbs

> Unlike other adverbs of degree, **enough** can only modify adverbs and adjectives.
>
> (https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Adverbs-of-Degree.htm)

Isn't *enough* used to modify verbs too?

Comment: Do you have an example? As outlined in the article, "I have done enough" is not an example.

Comment: In modern grammar, *enough* is classified as determinative. In "I've done enough" example, *enough* is also a determinative. But it's a somewhat different phrase structure. It's a fusion of determinative with the head, resulting in the omission of the head

Answer (score 1):

I think the blanket statement that *enough* cannot modify verbs is too broad. It can appear in a verb phrase when indicating a sufficient amount of time or number of occurrences:

- You have slept **enough** (for one afternoon).

  - Paraphrase: *long enough*
- I can't thank you **enough**.

  - Paraphrase: *often enough*, *enough times*